# Actionscript 3.0 Sprite Rotation Around Center Error

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, image-rotation

I found this actionscript online to rotate a sprite around its center point but I get two errors when I use it. **1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before leftparen. 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before leftbrace.** 
Also, in place of **angleDegrees** do I put in the angle I want the sprite to rotate by?

```
var point:Point=new Point(spr_box.x+spr_box.width/2, spr_box.y+spr_box.height/2);
    rotateAroundCenter(spr_box,45);

function rotateAroundCenter (ob:*, angleDegrees) {
    var m:Matrix=ob.transform.matrix;
    m.tx -= point.x;
    m.ty -= point.y;
    m.rotate (angleDegrees*(Math.PI/180));
    m.tx += point.x;
    m.ty += point.y;
    ob.transform.matrix=m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the Syntax errors, change this line:

`m.rotate (angleDegrees*(Math.PI/180));`

to this:

`m.rotate = (angleDegrees*(Math.PI/180));`

By the looks of it, you should use angleDegrees as the angle of displacement you want for your Sprite.

To improve that function, and make it easier to reuse, you could move the declaration of `point` inside the function.

Something like this:

```
function rotateAroundCenter(ob:DisplayObject, angleDegrees:Number) : void {
    var point:Point=new Point(ob.x + ob.width / 2, ob.y + ob.height / 2);

    var m:Matrix = ob.transform.matrix;
    m.tx -= point.x;
    m.ty -= point.y;
    m.rotate = (angleDegrees*(Math.PI/180));
    m.tx += point.x;
    m.ty += point.y;
    ob.transform.matrix = m;
}
```